# 2 different Leaflet Popup styles

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

Is it possible to have 2 different styles for Popups in Leaflet? 2 different popups (in terms of style and content) will be triggered on user interaction, one on `mouseover` and one on `click`.

**Problem:** I tried overiding the CSS style for `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper'` in the stylesheets which works for one popup style, that was not able to switch the CSS styles at runtime to switch back and forth between 2 CSS styles, probably because the popup DOM elements were not loaded yet.

```
marker.on('mouseover', function() {
    marker.bindPopup('<b>Hello world</b>');
    marker.openPopup();
})

marker.on('click', function() {
    marker.bindPopup('<b>Click click</b>');
    marker.openPopup();

    // Failed attempt to switch style
    $('.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper').addClass('new-style');
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `bindPopup` method can be passed an `"options"` parameter which can contain a `"className"` attribute that will be added to the div for the popup:

```
marker.on('mouseover', function() {
    marker.bindPopup('<b>Hello world</b>',{className: 'mouseover-popup'});
    marker.openPopup();
})

marker.on('click', function() {
    marker.bindPopup('<b>Hello world</b>',{className: 'click-popup'});
    marker.openPopup();
})
```

Comment: It would be great to see a fiddle demonstrating this functionality